# Image redraw one pixel at a time

Tags: android, image-processing

I want to take an image, get each pixel, change it to another color and update the image on the screen.

I can do all of this except the screen doesn't update after every pixel, it simply updates at the end of the loop - I'm presuming the OS or Java is handling this behind the scenes for me and simply showing me the end result when its done.

Anybody know how i can force the UI to show the image changing  real time?

Here is waht i have in my on click listener.
      operation= Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),
      bmp.getHeight(),bmp.getConfig());

```
  for(int i=0; i<bmp.getWidth(); i++){
     for(int j=0; j<bmp.getHeight(); j++){
        int p = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
        int r = Color.red(p);
        int g = Color.green(p);
        int b = Color.blue(p);
        int alpha = Color.alpha(p);



        r = (int) (Math.log(r)  +  r);
        g = (int) (Math.log(g)  + g);
        b = (int) (Math.log(b)  + b);
        alpha = (int) (Math.log(alpha) + alpha);

        operation.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(alpha, r, g, b));

     }
     img.setImageBitmap(operation);
```

Comment: Where is the code in your question being done? In an activity?  Lots of different options to do what you want.

Comment: Its being done directly in Activity, the class is hard coded to a button in the xml just for quickly starting up. Im open to any way that works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0; i<bmp.getWidth(); i++){
     for(int j=0; j<bmp.getHeight(); j++){
        int p = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
        int r = Color.red(p);
        int g = Color.green(p);
        int b = Color.blue(p);
        int alpha = Color.alpha(p);

        r = (int) (Math.log(r)  +  r);
        g = (int) (Math.log(g)  + g);
        b = (int) (Math.log(b)  + b);
        alpha = (int) (Math.log(alpha) + alpha);

        operation.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(alpha, r, g, b));
        img.setImageBitmap(operation);
        img.invalidate();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hey there. Apologies didnt check my alerts. This didnt appear to make a diff - i can still see the image unchanged until the entire image refresh at once with new coloring. I want to see each pixel change separately in real time.